# Show An Alert message Before Submitting the Page Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to create a alert message before submitting the page , my

form.py

```
class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):
   translated_names = TranslationField()

class Meta:
    fields = "__all__"
    model = models.Name
```

admin py

```
class NameAdmin(MasterDataBaseAdmin):
   form = forms.NameForm
   inlines = [AddressInline, RegistrationTypeInline]
   queryset = models.Name.objects.prefetch_related(
    "names", "name__id", "registrationstype"
)
```

views.py

```
class NameViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
     queryset = models.Country.objects.supported().prefetch_related("names", 
      "registrationstype")
      serializer_class = serializers.NameSerializer
```

I want to just add this meesage in the Message Box

"Are You Sure You Want To Save The Page!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your HTML

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" />
```

In your html you probably have something like that

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
<label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
<input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name" value="{{ current_name }}">
<input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" />
</form>
```

onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" here is your massage box

Comment: in the base html i have to add o

Comment: Add this to your form which you want to submit.

Comment: i really do not know where i should add the message  box , i addred  my form.py  , please tell me where i  need to add

Comment: I'm edit my answer. Check this.

Comment: Sure, I was asking in Name class how i can link the html , information